MongoDB .NET Driver - Aliasing fields in the projection
How to add alias in .NET 8 Blazor C# to change the field name?
var project = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("NameField").Include("_id")

How can I change the name NameField to just Name?
var client = new MongoClient();
var db = client.GetDatabase("DB");
var coll = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("CollectionName");

var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", id);
var query = coll.Find(filter);

How can I use the alias in this code?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

You can assign the projection with the BsonDocument instance. It works the same as writing the MongoDB query.
ProjectionDefinition<BsonDocument> projection = new BsonDocument
{
    { "_id", 1 },
    { "Name", "$NameField" }
};

var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", id);
var query = coll.Find(filter)
    .Project(projection);

